# Checking out equivalent branches causes untracked files to appear

Tags: git, version-control, branch, tracking

So I have 3 branches: `master`, `testing`, and `dev`. they all track respective branches on `remotes/origin` my `git branch -a` shows the following:

```
dev
master
testing
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/testing
remotes/origin/dev
```

When I release to testing I merge `dev` into `testing` then when I release the application I merge `testing` into `master` so `master` is effectively my release branch.

This has been working well for a while, I've had a few hiccups and had to do a few force pushes to `origin`. Not a big deal, small dev team and all. Recently I made a release so all of my branches are currently equivalent (`master` == `testing` == `dev` == `origin/master` == `origin/testing` == `origin/dev`)

Today, another developer and I noticed that when we did a `git checkout master` a ton of untracked/moved/deleted/renamed files show up when running `git status`. This is weird, because remember all of the branches are pointing to the same commit. How can this happen?

The only way to fix it is to do something like `git reset --hard origin/master` then I can switch to `testing` or `dev`. Weird thing is this doesn't happen when switching between `testing` and `dev`, just when I switch to `master`

Trying to debug this, I did a fresh clone of `origin` into a new directory. The fresh checkout has the same problem as our checkouts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info, when I do the `git checkout master` it complains about abiguous ref 'master'

**SOLUTION:**

For some reason I had a ref named `master` in `.git/refs/` It pointed to a *REALLY* old commit. so when I did `git checkout master` it complained about an ambiguous ref because there are two refs named master:

1. The local tracking branch `master` which tracks `origin/master`
2. This weird ref `master` I had hanging out at `.git/refs/master`

Hence the ambiguous refs complaint and the checkout command seemed to give the 2nd `master` preference. I deleted the file `.git/refs/master` and the issue went away.

I must have done something wrong during the clone, because I tried it again and it didn't give the extra `master` ref.